# PHP filter hashtags from string and write result back to file

Tags: php, filter, fopen, fwrite, cpu-word

I'm using `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to write some JSON content to a file.

My question: **Is there a way to filter the content and write only specific words to that file?**

E.g.: I retrive `"I #love #love #love you so #much my dear #brother!"` from the JSON file and I would like to **write only the word** `#love` and only one time to the file?

Here is an example of what I get in `$message`:

```
<p> #follow4follow #followme #follow #smile #happy #instalike #instadaily #instagood #life4like #like #likeback #fashion #fun #like4like #sweettooth #spring #gopro #love #tbt</p>
```

This is my starting point (`$message` writes the whole phrase to the file):

```
$myfile = fopen("custom/hashtag.php", "a");
fwrite($myfile, "<p>" . $message . "</p>" . " \n\r");

/////////////////////////////////////////////
//updated as @insertusernamehere suggested://
/////////////////////////////////////////////

$message = $comment['message']; //i get this from my json

$whitelist = array('#love');

// get only specific hashtag
preg_match_all('/' . implode('|', $whitelist) . '/', $message, $matches);

$unique_matches = array_unique($matches[0]);

$final = implode(' ', $unique_matches); 

$myfile = fopen("custom/hashtag.php", "a");

// to avoid empty results
if (!empty($unique_matches)) { 
   fwrite($myfile, "<p class=\"hidden\">" . $final . "</p>" . " \n\r");
}
```

Comment: 1. Where is your json? 2. What is in `$message` ?

Comment: @Rizier123 - I updated my post to show you what's inside  `$message `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
$message = 'I #love #love #love you so #much!';
```

**Get all hashtags using a regular expression**

```
preg_match_all('/#(\\w+)/', $message, $matches);
```

**Get only specific hashtags**

This is failsafe for similar tags like `#love` and `#loveYou`.

```
$whitelist = array('love', 'stackoverflow');
preg_match_all('/#\b(' . implode('|', $whitelist) . ')\b/', $message, $matches);
```

**Throw away duplicates**

```
$unique_matches = array_unique($matches[0]);
```

**Combine all hashtags using a whitespace for example**

```
print implode(' ', $unique_matches);
// prints "#love #much"
```

---

**Alternatively if you want to filter the list by allowed tags afterwards**

```
// create a whitelist of hashtags
$whitelist = array('#love', '#stackoverflow');
// filter the result by this list
$unique_matches_filtered = array_intersect($whitelist, $unique_matches);
// prints only "#love"
print implode(' ', $unique_matches_filtered);
```

Comment: Updated my post (sorry) i need to retrieve only a **specific** hashtag ( `#love`).

Comment: @isertusernamehere -  Can I use `preg_match_all('/#(\\w+)/', $message, $matches);` to filter `#love` instead of the `#` only?

Comment: @uomopalese You could also use `preg_match_all('/' . implode('|', $whitelist) . '/', $message, $matches);` to match only the exact hashtags you specified.

Comment: I get a strange result: `Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) #love ( [0] => #love ) Array ( )`  and the items in the file looks like this: `<p>1</p>` instead of  `<p>#love</p>`  .

Comment: @isertusernamehere  -  Sorry, my bad, there was an error in my code. Your code is working. I still get some empty  `<p></p>`. Is there a way to filter this too before to write the file? Thanks.

Comment: @uomopalese You can simply use `if (!empty($unique_matches)) { […] }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78670/discussion-between-uomopalese-and-insertusernamehere).

Comment: @uomopalese I've updated the regex in the answer to make it failsafe.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely PHP perspective, `explode()` your string into an array using the space between the words as your delimiter, use `array_unique()` to resolve your duplicate problem, and then use an array of acceptable words to compare to your array using `array_intersect()`. Write the result to your file.

Very ugly code not for production but it works:

```
<?php
$myallowedwordsarray = array("#love");

$stringtoclean = "I #love #love #love you so much!";

$arraytoclean = explode(" ", $stringtoclean);
$arraytocleanunique = array_unique($arraytoclean);
$cleanedarray = array_intersect($myallowedwordsarray, $arraytocleanunique);

echo $cleantext = implode($cleanedarray, " ");
```

Comment: @oxbeefly  -   your code seems to work, the only thing is i get some empty results in my file: `<p></p>` instead of  `<p>#love</p>`, how can i filter this too?

Comment: I would have to see your code. My code was just as an example - it will be very brittle (not able to handle all eventualities). My guess is you are writing to the file regardless of whether you find matches or not, giving the empty `<p>` tags

Comment: Just as a note, there's one little quirk in this solution: If you take the example string from the OP and you look for the hashtag `#brother` it will fail, as the element in `arraytoclean` will be `#brother!`.

Comment: @insertusernamehere - like I said:

**Very ugly code not for production but it works** (the text in the OP was edited after my solution was posted)